# xargs command fails on 'LINE_MAX' assertion

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash, xargs

I've been using git bash on Windows for a couple of years now and never had any real issues. Now I'm faced with a somewhat weird issue. Whenever the `xargs` command is used I get this error:

```
assertion "bc_ctl.arg_max >= LINE_MAX" failed: file "xargs.c", line 500, function: main
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The dumped core isn't particularly useful to me since it only contains Frame/Function/Args hexadecimal values:

```
 1 Stack trace:^M
 2 Frame        Function    Args^M
 3 000FFFFC370  0018005D14C (000FFFFE3F4, 00000000002, 000FFFFC4A0, 000FFFFDE50)^M
 ...
 15 End of stack trace
```

Even with a command as trivial as `xargs --version`, I still get the same result. I've searched and read many READMEs, blogs, and manuals, but I can't seem to find what's causing this. I know that the assertion means that my command is somehow bigger than LINE_MAX; which is this on my system:

```
workspace  $>getconf LINE_MAX
2048
```

But I don't see how `xargs --version` is bigger/longer than 2048.

Any help or tips is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing input to `xargs`? Are you running just "xargs --version"? Can you try like unhandled option like `xargs --something`? `line 500` Do you know what xargs/gnuutils version do you have? https://github.com/c9/node-gnu-tools/blob/master/findutils-src/xargs/xargs.c#L493

Comment: Same result with unhandled options. As far as the version I believe I'm on findutils 4.2.20 but I can't be sure since even the `--version` option doesn't work.

Comment: `xargs` tries to pack up arguments up to a certain number. If for some reason the limit is reached during `xargs` execution, it is probably a bug but you may be able to force the number of chars, e.g. `xargs --max-chars=1024`

Comment: Maybe try `find --version` to get version. the line 500 in [xargs 4.2.20](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/xargs/xargs.c?h=FINDUTILS_4_2_20-1&id=0d2407529718dc16784a41736dfb174f2419d2ce#n500) doesn't has the assertion. Try `which xargs` and `type xargs`. Try running `\xargs --version` - maybe something is masking the real xargs. [It's `4.6.0`  xargs.c](https://github.com/Distrotech/findutils/blob/v4.6.0/xargs/xargs.c#L500). `Might be nothing` - that's fine.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have this: `find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0`
@vdavid I tried that already with various values (1024, 2048, 99999) and it always returns the same error.

Comment: Might be nothing, but `type xargs` gives me this: `xargs is hashed (/usr/bin/xargs)`

Comment: Indeed options are parsed after this assertion, so it will throw everytime. Hm.... I think the best (and not-easy) would be to download xargs sources, compile them with debug information and debug it and see where exactly `bc_ctl.arg_max` is set to the value lower then `LINE_MAX`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Will do! It's pretty much what I thought my next step would be anyway.

Comment: What would output `getconf ARG_MAX` or `getconf _POSIX_ARG_MAX`? The output from `xargs --show-limits` would be helpful but will not work, because options are parsed after assertion.

Comment: ARG_MAX=32000 and _POSIX_ARG_MAX=4096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well, it turns out that some other scripts were sourced when my git bash loaded. They were company '.sh', since I'm on my work PC. One of them was breaking my xargs by interfering with a couple of configuration (including LINE_MAX). 
By 'unsourcing' these scripts I've solved my problem.

I'm still investigating the reason why `getconf` returned the proper values while `xargs` failed but at least I'm now able to use xargs properly.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't quote solve the problem. I have this too, but I don't have company `.sh` scripts happening before. Do we know how LINE_MAX is being changed.

Comment: Too large environment causes that, not something changing LINE_MAX (which is compile-time constant, not something that environment can change). Indeed, not sourcing something might decrease environment, and mitigate such a problem in some cases.

But it is possible to call xargs in a clean environment - if the paths of the called programs are known, using `env -i`. Like this:

`find $(FOO) -type d -print0 | env -i /usr/bin/xargs -0 /usr/bin/chmod a+x`